# Is there any point in blocking for a future?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Suppose I have an application serving many requests. One of the requests takes a while to complete. I have the following code:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future

def longReq(data:String):String = {
  val respFuture = Future{ 
     // some code that computes resp but takes a long time
     // can my application process other requests during this time?
     resp = ???  // time-consuming step
  }
  Await.result(respFuture, 2 minutes)
}
```

If I don't use futures at all, the application will be blocked until `resp` is computed and no other requests can be served in parallel during that time. However, if I use futures and then block for `resp` using `Await`, will the application be able to serve other requests in parallel while `resp` is being computed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, assuming that `longReq` is called serially by a request loop, the answer is **No, it cannot process anything else**. For that `longReq` would have to return a future instead:

```
def longReq(data:String): Future[String] = {
  Future { 
     // some code that computes resp but takes a long time
     // can my application process other requests during this time?
     resp = ???  // time-consuming step
  }
}
```

Of course that just pushes the reason you likely used `Await.result` further down the line.

The purpose of using `Future` is to avoid blocking, but it is a *turtles-all-the-way-down* buy-in. If you want to use a `Future`, the final recipient has to be able to deal with getting the result in an *asynchronous* way, i.e. your request loop must have a way to capture the caller in such a way that when the future is finally completed the caller can be told about the result

Let's assume your request loop receives a request object that a `response` callback, then you would call `longReq` like this (assuming the use of `longReq` that returns a `Future`):

```
def asyncCall(request: Request): Unit = {
  longReq(request.data).map( result => request.response(result) )
}
```

The most common scenario where you would use the flow is HTTP or other servers where the synchronous `Request => Response` cycle has an *async* equivalent of `Request => Future[Response]`, which pretty much any modern server framework offers (Play, Finatra, Scalatra, etc.)

**When to use `Await.result`**

The one scenario, where it might be reasonable to use `Await.result` is if you have a bunch of `Future`s and are willing to block while the all complete (assuming the use of `longReq` that returns a `Future`):

```
 val futures = allData.map(longReq))                // List[Future[String]]
 val combined = Future.sequence(futures)            // Future[List[String]]
 val responses = Await.result(combined, 10.seconds) // List[String]
```

Of course, `combined` being a `Future`, it would still be better to `map` over it and handle the result asynchronously

Comment: If the only purpose of this new thread waiting on the future is to take some action, you can just use the `onComplete` handler to take some action on future completion.